# Combinations without replacement with identical elements

Tags: combinatorics

What is the formula for calculating combinations without replacement and with identical elements?

For example, let's say I have a bag with 11 coins in it:

- 3 pennies
- 3 nickels
- 2 dimes
- 2 quarters
- 1 dollar coin

Coins of the same value are identical: they can't be distinguished from each other and are the same for creating combinations. If I take 4 random coins out of the bag, how many combinations are there?

Comment: The phrase "combinations without replacement" is a little confusing to me.  The term combinations suggests that there is no discernable order among items chosen, so that one can think of items being chosen *simultaneously*.  In that scenario there is naturally no replacement.  What's likely important is the intended application.  You might be concerned with counting how many outcomes are possible, or you might be concerned with counting in a way that reflects the *probability* of outcomes.  Additional context would be helpful to me in responding.

Comment: I only care about how many outcomes, not their probability.

Comment: Notice that you are asking for the number of solutions of the equation $$p + n + d + q + r = 4$$ in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions \begin{align*} p & \leq 3\\ n & \leq 3\\ d & \leq 2\\ q & \leq 2\\ r & \leq 1 \end{align*}  You could use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle or generating functions to handle the problem.

Comment: Well, that worked quite nicely to get the answer of 43.